# In SDL2 on OSX, how do I switch Joy-Con's control sticks from 'hat' to 'analog' mode?

Tags: macos, sdl-2, gamepad

SDL2 on OSX reads the Nintendo Joy-Con's analog stick as a hat, giving just a direction instead of an analog value. How do I switch modes on this controller to get analog input?

I'm using SDL version 2.0.9.

Answer (score 0):

The JoyCon doesn't appear to have special support in SDL 2.0.9. Out of the box JoyCon is just treated as a joystick, and there isn't an API to send it special configuration commands, but infrastructure to support the JoyCon appears in the source code; SDL does have special support for the Switch Pro controller.

The files that mention the JoyCon are part of the [Game Controller](https://wiki.libsdl.org/CategoryGameController) API. That API is designed to support controllers that are similar to the XBOX 360. A single JoyCon doesn't have enough inputs to fit into that category, which is probably why it is only available by default under the Joystick and not the GameController API.

SDL's [controllertype.h](https://github.com/spurious/SDL-mirror/blob/master/src/joystick/controller_type.h#L373) says:

```
// We currently don't support using a pair of Switch Joy-Con's as a single
// controller and we don't want to support using them individually for the
// time being, so these should be disabled until one of the above is true
// { MAKE_CONTROLLER_ID( 0x057e, 0x2006 ), k_eControllerType_SwitchJoyConLeft },    // Nintendo Switch Joy-Con (Left)
// { MAKE_CONTROLLER_ID( 0x057e, 0x2007 ), k_eControllerType_SwitchJoyConRight },   // Nintendo Switch Joy-Con (Right)
```

There is support for the Switch Pro controller however, in https://github.com/spurious/SDL-mirror/blob/master/src/joystick/hidapi/SDL_hidapi_switch.c ; it appears to be able to support all switch controller features using HID, even if they are not all exposed to SDL. This could probably command the JoyCon by un-commenting a few lines.

It's also possible to add a controller mapping to use a single joycon as a SDL gamecontroller, which can make the analog stick "hat" look like a digital joystick.

(Presumably the NDA'd port of SDL2 that runs on the Nintendo Switch has perfect support for JoyCons)